# Name of construction

Tags: java, construction

```
private final EventManager eventManager;
private final DateManager dateManager;
private final UserManager userManager;
```

What is the name of this construction? Is this object or something else? 
EventManager, DateManager, UserManager are the names of classes.

Answer (score 2):

It's called [field declaration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html). You are declaring that these [private, final] fields exist, with those names and types.

Answer (score 0):

Declaration of constant, *or* immutable, fields of types `EventManager`, `DateManager` and `UserManager`. Fields declared `final` can only be set once, by a constructor, they can't be modified after that.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring fields (class local variables). They are uninitalized (the objects don't exist yet, so no constructor has been called). They are set as final, meaning that they can only be assigned a value once, and you have not done that yet (so you have to do it in the construct).

If you wanted to define these AND call their constructor it would look like this

```
private final EventManager eventManager = new EventManager();
```

That would call the default constructor if it has one and initialized the field. Again, since the field is marked final and since in the above example it is being declared with a value, you can not set this value again, not even in the constructor.